# how to control Mono.zip(list) to execute one by one in reactor?

Tags: project-reactor

I have a list of Mono to run, but for memory consumption concern I'd like them to run one after another:

```java
var monos = [m1, m2, m3];
Mono.zip(monos, (results) -> {
  // handle result
});
```

The code above would execute m1 m2 m3 in parallel, how to control them in sequence and collect results?

Answer (score 2):

To run the Monos one after another in sequence, you can put your Monos in a Flux and call [`Flux.concatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-). To collect the results, you can use [`Flux.collectList`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--) to obtain a `Mono<List<T>>` that emits the list after the last Mono is finished:

```java
var monos = List.of(m1, m2, m3);
Flux.fromIterable(monos)
        .concatMap(mono -> mono)
        .collectList()
        .map(results -> ...) // handle results as a List<T>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out to use:

`Flux([1, 2, 3]).concatMap(...)` to solve this problem. Not sure if there are better way to do that.